# CucumberOptions tag is being ignored when @Suite Junit is used

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-junit

```
@Suite
@SuiteDisplayName("NAME")
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("cucumber/tests")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "cucumber.tests")
@CucumberOptions(tags = "not @IGNORE")
public class RunCucumberTests {}
```

This was my pervious configuration where the tag does not work

```
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("cucumber/tests")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "cucumber.tests")
@CucumberOptions(tags = "not @IGNORE")
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCucumberTests {}
```

After changing it this configuration it works. Does anyone knows why? How could I use suite and CucumberOptions together.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not use `@CucumberOptions` in combination with `@Suite`. The former is used for JUnit 4, the latter part of JUnit 5.

The `@Suite` annotation starts JUnit 5 declarative test suite. This means that you have to select the tests to execute using JUnit 5 concepts.

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#tags
- https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-tags

To target specific tags using the JUnit 5 suite, you have to use the `@IncludeTags` or `@ExcludeTags` annotations. For example:

```java
package io.cucumber.skeleton;

import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ConfigurationParameter;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.ExcludeTags;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.IncludeEngines;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.SelectClasspathResource;
import org.junit.platform.suite.api.Suite;

import static io.cucumber.junit.platform.engine.Constants.GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME;

@Suite
@IncludeEngines("cucumber")
@SelectClasspathResource("io/cucumber/skeleton")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = GLUE_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "io.cucumber.skeleton")
@ExcludeTags("IGNORE")
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

Note that these are JUnit 5 tags, and do not include the `@` symbol that Cucumber tags include.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `@ConfigurationParameter`:

```
@ConfigurationParameter(key = FILTER_TAGS_PROPERTY_NAME, value = "not @IGNORE")
```